# localStorage issue in IONIC/Cordova based mobile application

Tags: ios, html, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm using **localStorage** in my hybrid mobile app, which is developed using **ionicFramework**. Everything works fine, except **localStorage** uncertain behavior in IOS.

It works fine in Android.

**Bug Scenario:**

App login -> Use App -> Put the app to background
Don't use it for almost 4 hours -> Open the app

The localStorage gets empty. (And the app is logged out because the token from the localStorage is also missing)

Now force quit the app,and reopen it. All the localStorage values are restored and the app is again logged in. (mean missing values are again recovered).

I'm following the standard way to use localStorage i.e.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('key', value);
window.localStorage.getItem('key');
window.localStorage.removeItem('key');
```

I also used **AngularLocalStorage**, but it also had the same problem, because AngularLocalStorage is a wrapper over Local Storage...

**Cordova 5.4.1**
**IONIC Platform 1.1.1**

Comment: Hi, I'd like to recommend this [blog post](http://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/). TL;DR: you should not rely on localstorage for persistent data, as iOs may clean it at anytime (because memory's missing).

Comment: No, it is not about cleaning the data. If the data is cleaned by the OS, it should not be recovered/restored on app restart...

Comment: I did not say ERASE. But I may be wrong regarding this issue. Yet localStorage is not likely good to perform such data storage in hybrid apps.

Comment: What do you suggest me to use. If there is some option that has same structure as localStorage, it would be great...

Comment: I would recommend to use cordova SQLite database but you cant retrieve data before choosing the rout with `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()` so you may make a popover on the main page on your app which shows depending on the date got from the database. Also this link may help: [Don't Assume localStorage Will Always Work In Your Hybrid App](http://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/)

Comment: Use Ionic Storage. It is a wrapper over multiple driver options where localStorage is last in priority. If you build cordova app indeed use it with sqlite driver to get actual persistence